# Перенос блочного элемента на новую строку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Столкнулся с такой проблемой как перенос блоков на новую строку. Выровнял их в строку при помощи команды `float: left;` Нужно их разбить на группы, по 3 в строку.
Как рациональнее всего сделать переход на новую строку, а то добавлять кучу `<br>` как-то не красиво?
Выглядит всё [на данный момент вот так:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jkTju2nfHkcncyUFdBLXdpbkE/view)

```css
div.image1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

div.image2 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

div.image3 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>Pick materials</p>
<div class="color-params" id="col-params" style="display: block;">

  <p> Choose a color </p>
  <div class="image1">
    <div id="image001">
      <img src="\Users\cruel\Desktop\htmllll\color1.jpg" width="80">
      <div class="select-image"></div>
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="col" class="radio" id="radio-001" value="001"> "color1"
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="image1">
    <div id="image002">
      <img src="\Users\cruel\Desktop\htmllll\color2.jpg" width="80">
      <div class="select-image"></div>
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="col" class="radio" id="radio-002" value="002"> "color2"
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="image1">
    <div id="image003">
      <img src="\Users\cruel\Desktop\htmllll\color3.jpg" width="80">
      <div class="select-image"></div>
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="col" class="radio" id="radio-003" value="003"> "color3"
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="elbow-params" id="el-params">
  <div class="image2">
    <div id="image004">
      <img src="\Users\cruel\Desktop\htmllll\elbow1.jpg" width="80">
      <div class="select-image"></div>
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="elb" class="radio" id="radio-004" value="004"> "elbow1"
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="image2">
    <div id="image005">
      <img src="\Users\cruel\Desktop\htmllll\elbow2.jpg" width="80">
      <div class="select-image"></div>
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="elb" class="radio" id="radio-005" value="005"> "elbow2"
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="image2">
    <div id="image006">
      <img src="\Users\cruel\Desktop\htmllll\elbow3.jpg" width="80">
      <div class="select-image"></div>
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="elb" class="radio" id="radio-006" value="006"> "elbow3"
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="wheel-params" id="whl-params" style="display:block;">
    <div class="image3">
      <div id="image007">
        <img src="\Users\cruel\Desktop\htmllll\wheel1.jpg" width="80">
        <div class="select-image"></div>
      </div>

      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="whl" class="radio" id="radio-007" value="007"> "wheel1"
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="image3">
      <div id="image008">
        <img src="\Users\cruel\Desktop\htmllll\wheel2.jpg" width="80">
        <div class="select-image"></div>
      </div>

      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="whl" class="radio" id="radio-008" value="008"> "wheel2"
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="image3">
      <div id="image009">
        <img src="\Users\cruel\Desktop\htmllll\wheel3.jpg" width="80">
        <div class="select-image"></div>
      </div>

      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="whl" class="radio" id="radio-009" value="009"> "wheel3"
      </p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в `CSS` блока, который должен быть на новой строке `clear: both;`

```
.image1:first-child, .image2:first-child, .image3:first-child {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: В таком случае все приобретает такой вид https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3jkTju2nfHkNC1pTWRXcDMtN00

Comment: Дополнил ответ выше, стиль надо применить к первому элементу каждой группы

Comment: Спасибо, попробую